# fatal: unknown style 'diff5' given for 'merge.conflictstyle'

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, git-checkout, git-diff

```
$ git checkout sidebar
fatal: unknown style 'diff5' given for 'merge.conflictstyle'
```

I am trying to change branch in my Git repository. Why do I get this error? How to fix it?

Comment: It's complaining that your setting for `merge.conflictstyle` isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

**`diff5` is not a valid setting for `merge.conflictstyle`.**

You should use `merge`:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle merge
```

...or `diff3`:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

[More information in Git's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-mergeconflictStyle)

Answer (score 0):

git has an option to display merge conflicts in diff3 format (by default it only displays the two files to be merged). You can enable it like so:

```
 $ git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```